# Django html variables are splitting when binding

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a simple html template which shows permissions in a table for each group. Every cell of the table, contains a button. I want to show the name of the permission in a popover of every button!
The problem is that Django variable is not working fine!

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn" title={{ permission.name }}>
    ...
</button>
```

As you can see in above, the `title` is initialized with `{{ permission.name }}` and I expect to see full name of permission when hovering button, but it just contains the first word! Which is not odd because this is what I saw in the inspect elements:

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn" title="نمایش" لیست="" کاربران="">
    ...
</button>
```

As you can see, `title` is ruined!
What's the problem here? Why it's not working as I expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing the quotes "{{permission.name}}":

```html
<button type="submit" class="btn" title="{{ permission.name }}">
    ...
</button>
```